# Spring MVC/Boot access simple model with Groovy Templates

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot

Can't figure out how to access a model property within a Groovy Layout template.

All I want is to be able to render a cdn url or local dev url for css, js etc...

IndexController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    ActiveProfileUtil activeProfileUtil;

    @Autowired
    DeviceChooserUtil deviceChooserUtil;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndex(Device device, Model model) {

        System.out.println(activeProfileUtil.getActiveProfile());

        model.addAttribute("profiles", activeProfileUtil.getActiveProfile());

        String deviceType = deviceChooserUtil.getDeviceView(device, "index");

        return deviceType;

    }

}
```

The sys out prints correctly

I have an if statement in the groovy layout that should see the profiles model and render the link accordingly.

Common Layout

```
yieldUnescaped '<!DOCTYPE html>'
html {
    head (lang:'en'){
        meta(charset:'utf-8')
        title(pageTitle)
        if (profiles == 'production')
            script(src:'http://cdn.somehost.com/assets/js/desktop.js'){}
        else
            script(src:'assets/js/desktop.js'){}
    }
    body {
        div(class:'container') {
            mainBody()
        }
    }
}
```

Currently nothing happens it always renders false.  If I change to != it will always render true.

`activeProfileUtil.getActiveProfile()` is a method that returns a String either production or development

index.tpl

```
layout 'desktop/layouts/common.tpl',
profiles: profiles,
pageTitle: 'Test Title',
mainBody: contents {
    div(class:'row') {
        div(class:'col-md-12') {
        h1("H1 Title")
            p('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was fairly easy.  Was trying to pass the `profiles` to the common layout template.  Instead needed to pass `profiles` to the index.tpl

This corrected the issue
`profiles: profiles`

Have not been able to find a lot of documentation about Groovy Templates so asked the question before I thought about the logic.